# Datetime value to string by replacing c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a **datetime** value below,

```
23/07/2014 04:15:00
```

How can i get date as below string value

```
23/07/2014
```

How can i get hour as below string value

```
04:15 AM/PM (depends hour time)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: look at datetime.ToString("specify your format here"). If your is custom one then manupulate your string accordingly.

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'd parse the string to `DateTime` first to avoid string manipulation.

```
var str = "23/07/2014 04:15:00";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//23/07/2014
var time = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//04:15 AM
```

If you have the value as `DateTime` you can skip `ParseExact` part.

Comment: I guess that he has already a `DateTime` since he mentions "I have a datetime value" (but i'm not sure). Note that your approach without the `InvariantCulture` in `ToString` will use the current culture's date-separator even if you specify "dd/MM/yyyy" which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx#dateSeparator).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Honestly, I overlooked it as string, anyway I hope this would be helpful in both the cases. :) Added `InvariantCulture` also..

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, am aware of that, that's why I used it in `ParseExact`, my bad forgot while converting back to string. anyway thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @JohnElizabeth You're not supposed to talk like this when you need help. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really use a `DateTime` instead of a string, but you should. If not, you can use `DateTime.Parse`/`DateTime.TryParseExact` to get a `DateTime` from a `string`.

`DateTime` has a method `ToShortDateString`

```
string dateOnly = dt.ToShortDateString();
// or to force / as separator even if current culture has different separator
dateOnly = dt.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// hour+minute and AM/PM designator:
string hour = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* feel like taking a risk to answer your question but.. anyway.

> How can i get date as below string value

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 7, 23, 4, 15, 0);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")); // 23/07/2014
```

I escaped `/` character because it has a special meaning in custom date and time format strings. It means as; *replace me with the current culture date separator*. Take a look [`"/"` Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) for more information.

> How can i get hour as below string value

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
04:15 AM
```